# "Command not found" passing argument from Makefile to shell script

Tags: shell-script, shell, make, gnu, gnu-make

I have a `info.properties` file where I have this `MY_NAME` property and I can use this property on my `Makefile`. I already tried but I can't use that property directly on `myScript.sh` file.

So I'm trying to pass that property as argument to `myScript.sh`. And I'm doing like this:

**On Makefile:**

```
my_stage:
    chmod 777 myScript.sh && ./myScript.sh $(MY_NAME)
```

**On myScript.sh I have this:**

```
#!/bin/bash -e
source .build/utils.sh

MY_NAME=$1
echo "MY_NAME=${MY_NAME}"
```

But I'm always getting this error:

```
chmod 777 myScript.sh && ./myScript.sh My-name-Mariana
.build/utils.bash: line 596: My-name-Mariana: command not found
make: *** [test] Error 127
```

How can I solve this?

**UPDATE:**

I know `.build/utils.bash` is tryind to execute my parameter, I can see that on the error. But I can't change that file because I don't have it because is not part of my code project.

Comment: The error seems to be coming from deep inside a file called `.build/utils.bash` that you don't mention (is this file itself sourced from `.build/utils.sh`?)

Comment: Well, if make is installed which it should be, you can try removing the `-e`  and see where it takes you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your script can source `.build/utils.bash`, you have already proved that you in fact *can* read it. For example, try `less .build/utils.bash` in the directory that contains the Makefile.

To fix the actual problem without modifying `.build/utils.bash`, you might try assigning the contents of `$1` into your `MY_NAME` variable and then using the `shift` command to remove it from `$1` - **before** you `source .build/utils.sh`.

But then `utils.bash` receives `$1` as an empty string, which may cause it to fail or to do something different - without reading `utils.bash` or some documentation about it, it will be impossible to know what it expects.

Answer (score 3):

On line 596 (or so) of your `.build/utils.bash` script you are trying to call `My-name-Mariana` as a command. Either as a literal or as `$1`. It doesn't exist so the execution fails immediately (due to the `-e` flag on `bash`).

> ```
> .build/utils.bash: line 596: My-name-Mariana: command not found
> ```

The solution is to fix the code. You've not provided it here so we can't offer an specific suggestion, but I'm sure someone would be happy to do so if you updated your question with the relevant context.

Comment: I made an update to my question. I don't have `.build/utils.bash`. And I already know that file is trying to execute my parameter. But how can I over come that?

Comment: @Ninita who wrote `myScript.sh`, or where did it come from?